# jQuery cookie. Функция

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie, localstorage

Доброго времени суток!
Есть такая задача:
Есть 3 блока, при нажатие на блок он скрываются (аккордеон), это уже реализовано.
Нужно что бы при нажатие на блок записывалась одна кука а при повторном нажатии другая, например: 1 | 0
Потом при обновлении страницы проверялась кука.
Если значение 1 то блок показывается, если 0, то скрывается.

Другими словами:
Нужно чтобы браузер запоминал действие пользователя при сворачивании/разворачивании аккордеона.

[image: Скриншот]

Я новичок. Написал такой код:

```
    //проверка куки
if(myCookie !== null){
    $(".tab_wrap .tab_chords").css("display", "none");
} else{
    $(".tab_wrap .tab_chords").css("display", "block");
}

//Переключение куки
$(".tab_wrap h2").on("click", function(){
    var th = $(this);

    if(th.is($(".acordeon-active"))){ //Если аккордеон открыт
        $.cookie('block1', 1, {
            expires: 5, //Сколько будет хринится кука (дней)
        });
        var myCookie = $.cookie('block1', 1)
    } else{
        var myCookie = $.cookie('block1', null);
    }
});
```

Я понимаю что переменная не видна из другой функции.

Comment: Лучше для этого использовать хранилище.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите как реализовать?

Comment: Дал ответ......

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#toggleInfo'),
  info = document.querySelector('#info'),
  btnValue = btn.dataset.open;
    
if(localStorage['isOpen'] == 1){
 btnValue = btn.dataset.close;
  info.style.display = 'block';
}

btn.value = btnValue;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
 this.value = this.value === this.dataset.open ? this.dataset.close : this.dataset.open;
  
  if(getComputedStyle(info, null).display === 'none'){
   info.style.display = 'block';
    localStorage['isOpen'] = 1;
  }else{
   info.style.display = 'none';
    localStorage['isOpen'] = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
#info{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='info'>
  Sexy and I Know It
</div>
<input type='button' id='toggleInfo' data-close='Скрыть надпись' data-open='Открыть надпись' value='Кнопка' />
```